# How I can get a focus message in MFC?

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

I have a dialog box with some CListCtrl. I want that when I click on one of them, receive killfocus or setfocus message.

How I can get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`CListCtrl` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfshke78.aspx) wraps the Win32 ListView control. That control communicates with its parent (your dialog) via [`WM_NOTIFY` messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775583.aspx).

So you can process `WM_NOTIFY` messages from your list control in your dialog class. Use the Properties window to create an [`OnChildNotify` handler function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k689yez.aspx) and write a `switch` statement that handles the notification message(s) of interest.

The possible notification messages are listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774737.aspx) in the Windows SDK documentation.